# Altium: What is the purpose of layers 1, 13 and 15 in this PCB footprint?

Tags: altium, footprint

What is the purpose of data contained in the mechanical layers of this PCB footprint.

Here is a PCB foot print I got from snapeda for the part OF-SMD2835G.

[image]

The green line appears to be outline for use in assembly drawing but I could be wrong. The pink lines are too small than the pads so they could indicate the outline of the actual part itself on the PCB. Is this correct?

The main issue is that there is no layer type assigned for these layers. If a layer type is not assigned means that the data is ambigious. Does SnapEDA expect that end user will assign the layer type according the convention they have adopted for their project?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altium default layers are (or, at least were when I learned it):

- Mech 1: part centroid
- Mech 13: 3D information (ComponentBody object(s) and outlines)
- Mech 15: part courtyard

I usually just toss all these onto the same output layers anyway (as part of the assembly drawing) so it doesn't make much difference there.  I don't know how exactly CMs (Contract Manufacturers) use them, but they are exported in the ODB++ output (which CMs may use), or the raw EDA file (PcbDoc) of course (which is becoming a more common exchange format these days, interestingly enough).

Remember to set mechanical layer pairs on the PCB, when placing components on both sides.  For example, I usually use (top/bottom) Mech 1/3, 13/14 and 15/16 (only skipping 2 because I've used that for other things in the past, whatever, it's just an example).  This way, components on the bottom side don't show up on top Mech 13 and etc. when you generate the top side assembly drawing.

I think these settings or pairings are more automated, or better categorized and more evident, in recent versions (AD20+).

Comment: Thanks Tim. This question is specifically about PCB foot print, do we need to have layer pairs in the PCB footprint itself as well?

Comment: Libraries do not support layer pairs.

Comment: We can add component layer pairs into Altium PCB footprint. Mechanical layes are not in pairs.

Answer (score 2):

They're mechanical layers (of user-defined purpose) so they should not directly affect the PCB manufacturing  unless they are specifically called out as the overall PCB outline or something like that.

The green looks like part of a courtyard layer pair, intended to prevent components from being placed too close to each other or overlapping without generating a DRC error. One of the magenta layers  likely contains a 3D STEP model of the part (the cross-hatched area), and the other (the horizontal lines) may be intended for an assembly drawing.

If you get libraries from different sources rather than just making them yourself you will likely run into incompatible definitions of the mechanical layers so you may have to do some work to adapt them to your own standards.

See below for designating mechanical layer types:

[image]

Keep in mind, there's nothing forcing you to create or use courtyards, 3D models, assembly layers etc. All you really need is what is on the layers that will directly create the Gerber files and NC drill files and (typically) a layer with the outline. For a simple two-layer board with solder mask and silk screen both sides that's a total of 6 layers (3 layer pairs) plus an outline mechanical layer. That typically results in 7 gerber files and one or two drill files (depending on whether you have non-plated holes).

Comment: I guess the only step is to ensure that they are in the correct layer number that matches how things are done on my end, or is it also that the layer type must be declared?

Comment: If you want the courtyard to work I think you have to declare the type for the DRC functions to apply. The 3D models should show anyway in the 3D view if the layer visibility is enabled. It might be confusing at some point if some of the models, but not all, disappear when one layer is visible and the other isn't.

Comment: OK lets clear this. I have seen Mechanical 1 having the 3D model. Then we need one layer to contain the thing which shall appear in the assembly drawing and another layer to contain the thing that is used to describe the "courtyard" of the part. I assume that the courtyard information shall be used in DRC at some point. Is this true? Also, specifically how do we specify which layer shall give the courtyard information and which will give the assembly layer information?

Comment: See above edit for layer type definition. I believe clearance DRC uses both courtyard and 3D models for clearance. If you call the layer an assembly layer you can use it for an assembly layer, but if you leave it as M22 or whatever you can also use it for an assembly layer (the name is just for convenience).

Comment: If I used a canned part (almost never), I'll reconfigure the part to match my convention.

Comment: @qrk This is the way, IMO.

Comment: I am intrigued by the methodology of Spehro. Are these layers used with PCB footprints? Is there a specific reason for having all the custom layers as pairs? How are the "info layers" used? Also, how does Altium know which layer to use for courtyard information?

Comment: The board stack layers are in pairs.

Comment: @quantum231 pairs are relevant because you want mirrored behavior when you move the same footprint to the opposite side of a board. It’s built in to the program. I think you have to call the layer courtyard for it to be used, but I don’t generally use it myself for the kind of work I do the silk screen markings and manual placement is more than adequate. If you’re laying out HDI boards with cell-phone like density that probably won’t be enough.

Comment: "you want mirrored behavior when you move the same footprint to the opposite side of a board", I thought Altium will be smart enough to know what to do if a part is moved to bottom side of board, so that is actually not the case?

Comment: Yes it is smart enough.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, green line is Mech 15-Courtyard; pink lines are the edges and pink hashed square is the total component body area on Mech 13 (usually Nominal, unless you selected Least or Most). Yellow is silk, or "Top Overlay".

SnapEDA, Ultra Librarian, and any other distributors of symbols/footprints have to create a base file which can be translated into any CAD tool the user defines. That's why you have to choose your CAD tool when you download a file: their tool translates it into an acceptable base format that your tool can read. And, since mech layers are largely user defined, they will come in with no names attached. 3D bodies are nearly always in .stp format, and every CAD tool knows how to read them, so you don't have to specify, though some specific suppliers will allow you to choose your 3D body format when you download directly from their site.

I've gotten around this in the past by creating a template which has all my mech layers, preferred grid, colors, etc loaded; but with no primitives. Then I just select all of the primitives on the downloaded file and paste them into my template. Altium will, for example, automatically plug information on mech 13 from the download onto mech 13 on my template, which I've called "3D Body Outline" or similar.

I've seen a lot of comments bandied about in the vein of "use Mech layers for whatever you want," and- to an extent- that's accurate. There are more than enough layers available in the tool to include whatever information you may need internally, and/or whatever you need to communicate to your CM.

That said, there are industry norms around certain layers. For example:
Mech 3 = Top Assembly,
Mech 13 = 3D Body (outline and/or object),
Mech 15 = Top Courtyard.

These layers of course need to be paired with their equivalent on the bottom side of the board if the design needs to use that space. Altium will not automatically "know" what your artwork primitives represent- it only knows what you tell it as far as mechanical layer definition and therefore mechanical layer functions. But it is smart enough to understand that if the Top Courtyard is paired with a Bottom Courtyard, the primitives on these layers represent the same information, and are subject to the same rules.

There are default rules around courtyards (how much clearance from courtyard to component, how much clearance between components' courtyards) already defined in the tool (and these are based on IPC standards. If you don't know what those are, LOOK THEM UP RIGHT NOW. See below for reference numbers). Or you can create your own courtyard, or you can turn these rules off so Altium won't squawk at you. But they are there for a reason, and you ignore them at your peril. A hand-soldered component needs extra clearance to fit the soldering iron in without frying adjacent components, for example. It's worth it to draw a generous courtyard and let Altium call you out if you subsequently try to place another component too close. Or alternately, you'll create interference between traces if components are placed too closely and routed based on that placement.

I've been told in a professional Altium training not to use mech 1 for anything because Altium uses it. This is illustrated (in PCBLib file) in Tools > Manage 3D Bodies for Current Component. You'll notice your footprint on the left, and as you click down through the Description lines, either the information will be user-visible on the right, or not. The invisible information is... you guessed it.... on Mech 1.  **Be careful with this dialog box: by clicking in the "Body State" column, you can turn on or turn off the 3D body (ie: you can disappear it), but it is still "there". Altium just might freak out if you then try to paste another 3D body in the same place on the same layer. I wouldn't risk playing with it!

That said, I don't think you'd run into any major issues with functionality of your Gerbers or ODB++ output files- that is, unless your CM tells you they're messed up. Each CM has their own standards and quirks, and they may request/require specifics re: mech layers. It’s worth it to check with the CM before file submission to see what they require. Depending on what they use to open, read, and manipulate your files, they could run into confusing or garbled information if mech 1 has additional information on it. Better to just leave that one alone, imo. There's 32 others to choose from, after all.

There are mech layers which are default, so you don't need to define them, and they're so standard that Altium doesn't even give them numbers. They are: "Overlay," "Paste," and "Solder." They will appear with their paired bottom side equivalents in any new PCBLib file you open. Mech 1 will also appear as default in a new file (I assume because Altium always uses it). These are visible/editable in the View Configuration panel. If your imported footprint has this information on a different mech layer, simply select those primitives (Single Layer Mode toggle function: SHIFT + S to select only desired primitives), and use the “Layers” dropdown in the Properties panel to change the layer assignment.

Loooooooong story short: mech layers are useful, they are important, and if you are not just a home hobbyist you’ll need to understand and use them to create boards that work and which are reproducible. Proper design will also save a TON of money in production phase!

FOR MORE INFO, SEE:

**IPC-2221A** -- "The standard for the PCB design process. Covered in this process are materials, design, electrical & thermal properties, and much more. IPC-2221 addresses topics, such as design layout, mechanical and physical properties, parts lists, materials, electrical properties, thermal management, and more. "

**IPC-7351** -- "defines the size, shape, and tolerance for the surface mount pads that go on your board. Adhering to these standards enables your manufacturer to establish a reliable electrical connection between the solder fillets and the components. This avoids manufacturing defects caused by land patterns."

https://www.twistedtraces.com/blog/important-ipc-standards-for-pcb-manufacturing

https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/working-with-mechanical-layers

https://resources.altium.com/p/pcb-land-pattern-design-ipc-7351-standard

https://www.ultralibrarian.com/2022/02/01/ipc-7351-explaining-the-standard-for-pcb-footprints-ulc

Comment: After much research and contemplation what I have found is that the Altium itself has evolved over the years. Today we need to use layer pairs and not solitary mechanical layers. When we create layer pair, we can specify what kind of information they will contain e.g 3D body, component courtyard e.t.c. What this means is that the layer numbers do not exactly matter in the individual footprints since we also define what each layer pair contains but it is still better to be consistent. So basically since layer pairs mean that footprint works correctly when we flip from top sie to bottom ...

Comment: ... it means that mechanical layers don't serve any purpose under normal circumstances. Everything needs to go into layer pairs. Your answer is still helpful since it contains links to important pieces of information. The Altium applications engineer has created a video (few weeks ago) that goes into detail of how footprint needs to be created in Altium. It describes the essential things that must be present in it. Some comments exists under that youtube video that clarify the things that the video missed.

Comment: I agree. I think the most important thing is consistency across the entire library of components coupled with a clear understanding of what your CM prefers/requires for fab & assembly. IMO, sticking with accepted norms for layer numbers and terminology will only help to avoid confusion and production snags.